# Orion-QL subscription configuration

Tags: fiware, throttling, fiware-orion

I have devices with many IoT-sensors. I want to batch read from these devices and batch write this data to **CrateDB**. 100 data is obtained from the sensors every 1 second.

How can I take, for example, 5 seconds of batch data (500 data) **at once** with the Quantum Leap agent and write it to CrateDB?Should I do this configuration in **Orion-QL subscription** (throttling etc)?

Answer (score 1):

With NGSI-v2 batch update is achieved using the `/v2/op/update` endpoint e.g. :

```sh
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/v2/op/update' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data-raw '{
  "actionType":"update",
  "entities":[
    {
      "id":"urn:ngsi-ld:Product:001", "type":"Product",
      "price":{"type":"Integer", "value": 1199}
    },
    {
      "id":"urn:ngsi-ld:Product:002", "type":"Product",
      "price":{"type":"Integer", "value": 1199},
      "size": {"type":"Text", "value": "L"}
    }
  ]
}'
```

With NGSI-LD you can use `/ngsi-ld/v1/entityOperations/upsert`:

```sh
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/entityOperations/upsert' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-H 'Link: <http://path-to-context/ngsi-context.jsonld>; rel="http://www.w3.org/ns/json-ld#context"; type="application/ld+json"' \
-H 'Accept: application/ld+json' \
--data-raw '[
    {
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:002",
      "type": "TemperatureSensor",
      "category": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": "sensor"
      },
      "temperature": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": 21,
            "unitCode": "CEL"
      }
    },
    {
      "id": "urn:ngsi-ld:TemperatureSensor:003",
      "type": "TemperatureSensor",
      "category": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": "sensor"
      },
      "temperature": {
            "type": "Property",
            "value": 27,
            "unitCode": "CEL"
      }
    }
]'
```

You didn't state if your multisensor was capable of sending NGSI calls - if it can't send NGSI, but able to send batch readings in some other format, then you just need a microservice to do the conversion for you -  an example can be found here on [GitHub](https://github.com/jason-fox/csv-to-json) - commentary on the code can be found in the [Video Tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HuEwI8wJKFU&t=1608s) from FIWARE Foundation.

Once you have safely send your device data in NGSI format, you can tackle the second half of your question. There are QuantumLeap tutorials for both [NGSI-v2](https://fiware-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/time-series-data.html) and [NGSI-LD](https://ngsi-ld-tutorials.readthedocs.io/en/latest/time-series-data.html), the key to them both is creating a subscription notifying of any changes.

#### NGSI-v2

```sh
curl -iX POST \
  'http://localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions/' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'fiware-service: openiot' \
  -H 'fiware-servicepath: /' \
  -d '{
  "description": "Notify QuantumLeap of count changes of any Motion Sensor",
  "subject": {
    "entities": [
      {
        "idPattern": "Motion.*"
      }
    ],
    "condition": {
      "attrs": [
        "count"
      ]
    }
  },
  "notification": {
    "http": {
      "url": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify"
    },
    "attrs": [
      "count"
    ],
    "metadata": ["dateCreated", "dateModified"]
  }
}'
```

#### NGSI-LD

```sh
curl -L -X POST 'http://localhost:1026/ngsi-ld/v1/subscriptions/' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/ld+json' \
-H 'NGSILD-Tenant: openiot' \
--data-raw '{
  "description": "Notify me of all feedstock changes",
  "type": "Subscription",
  "entities": [{"type": "FillingLevelSensor"}],
  "watchedAttributes": ["filling"],
  "notification": {
    "attributes": ["filling", "location"],
    "format": "normalized",
    "endpoint": {
      "uri": "http://quantumleap:8668/v2/notify",
      "accept": "application/json"
    }
  },
   "@context": "http://path-to-context/ngsi-context.jsonld"
}'
```

The `throttling` parameter is not necessary unless you only want to sample the incoming data.

Comment: So I want to batch process many attributes in a single entity, not many entity updates, is this possible? @JasonFox

Comment: Many attributes in one entity is just a simple PATCH `/entities/<urn:entity-id>`. You can use NGSI directly or use an IoT Agent for this (which actually uses the batch endpoint behind the scenes, but the batch upsert is just the one entity)

Comment: A single attribute in one entity is  PATCH `/entities/<urn:entity-id>/attrs`